# badRecordsPath in EMR+Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, databricks

I am looking for a solution to enforce schema in apache spark read file.My file example is as below.

```
"1"~"SLACK"~2000
"2"~"GII"~2010
"3"~2015
```

I am looking for a solution to identify the third row. I am using EMR+Spark.I know there is an option in databricks spark distribution about **badRecordsPath** but not able to find out the same in spark within EMR.

Comment: Any solution or suggestions of above problems.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that option is only available with databricks distribution, but not sure.
You can try the below approach

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").
    .option("delimiter", delimiter)
    .schema("_c0 String, C1 String, C2 Integer, _corrupt_record String")
    .load("/tmp/output/path/")
```

Later you can filter

```
val badRows = df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull)
```